# How to use quotation mark in EL Strings?

Tags: jsf, el

I get the Error: `EL Expression Unbalanced` while trying to add quotation mark in EL String. How can I do that?

```
#{chainModel.selectedChain.equalsIgnoreCase("") 
    ? 'Kettenbearbeitung' : 
    'Verkettung'
    .concat('"')
    .concat(chainModel.selectedChain)
    .concat('"')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `\&quot;` ASCII HTML Names to avoid JSF Syntax validations when you need to concat JAVA values with complex strings. Or use `\"` for double quotes or `\'` for simple quotes and it will be simplified when you need for a simple string.

In your case I propouse the following:

```
? 'Kettenbearbeitung' :
'Verkettung'
.concat('\&quot;') 
.concat(chainModel.selectedChain)
.concat('\&quot;')
```